# How to call S3.putObject (or S3.upload) and use a gzip stream as body

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, zlib

As our logging mechanism is not able to create big gz-files, I'm trying to do it with a lambda. It works when I load all of them from S3 into the memory and afterwards create the gzip file. But this needs too much memory. This is why I try the following: Start a gzip stream into memory and when I receive the content of a file from S3, I write it to the gzip stream. Without luck. Besides other ideas, I tried the code below.

I read from here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2961 that the aws-sdk needs to know the length of a stream. That's why I use the streamToBuffer function which was also described on the given link.

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const stream = require('stream')

async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  const chunks = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)))
    readableStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
    readableStream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)))
  })
}

const gzip = zlib.createGzip()
gzip.setEncoding('utf8')

for (let ii = 0; ii < files.length; ii++) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: srcBucket,
    Key: `${files[ii]}`,
  };
  console.log('Get:', params.Key, 'from:', params.Bucket);
  var resp = await s3.getObject(params).promise().catch(err=>{
    console.log(err, err.stack)
    return 'Failed to list objects'
  })
  
  gzip.write(resp.Body);
}

gzip.flush()
gzip.end()

var destPath = files[0].replace(srcPrefix, destPrefix).replace('.txt','.gz')

var msg = 'merging ' + srcBucket + ':' + currentPrefix + '* to ' + srcBucket + ':' + destPath

console.log('Attempting: ' + msg);
const data = await s3.putObject({
  Bucket: srcBucket,
  Key: destPath,
  Body: await streamToBuffer(gzip)
}).promise().catch(err => {
  console.log('Error: ' + msg)
  console.log(err, err.stack)
  return -1
})

if (data === -1) {
  return 'Error while putting new object to S3'
}
  
console.log('Success: ' + msg);
console.log(data);
```

The code puts a file to S3. **However, it is not a correct gzip-file**. I'm not able to open it. I know the code is not really nice. But it should work, I think. Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that the log files are text files conainting json entries. There are not already gzipped.

**UPDATE:** I tried the same with s3.upload instead of s3.putObject using directly the gzip stream as upload should support it. It leads to the this error:

```
"The \"list[0]\" argument must be an instance of Buffer or Uint8Array. Received type string ('\\u001f\ufffd\\b\\u0000\\u0000\\u0...)"
```

Setting `gzip.setEncoding('utf8')` to `gzip.setEncoding(null)` as described here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2081 did not help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it working!
I don't have to set the encoding for gzip but during the **write**. This is my code which is creating correct gzip-files:

```js
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const stream = require('stream')

async function streamToBuffer(readableStream) {
  const chunks = []
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    readableStream.on('data', (chunk) => chunks.push(Buffer.from(chunk)))
    readableStream.on('error', (err) => reject(err))
    readableStream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)))
  })
}

const gzip = zlib.createGzip()

for (let ii = 0; ii < files.length; ii++) {
  const params = {
    Bucket: srcBucket,
    Key: `${files[ii]}`,
  };
  console.log('Get:', params.Key, 'from:', params.Bucket);
  var resp = await s3.getObject(params).promise().catch(err=>{
    console.log(err, err.stack)
    return 'Failed to list objects'
  })
  
  // Add the encoding to create correct gzip files!
  gzip.write(resp.Body, 'utf-8');
}

gzip.flush()
gzip.end()

var destPath = files[0].replace(srcPrefix, destPrefix).replace('.txt','.gz')

var msg = 'merging ' + srcBucket + ':' + currentPrefix + '* to ' + srcBucket + ':' + destPath

console.log('Attempting: ' + msg);
const data = await s3.putObject({
  Bucket: srcBucket,
  Key: destPath,
  ContentType: "application/json",
  ContentEncoding: "gzip",
  Body: await streamToBuffer(gzip)
}).promise().catch(err => {
  console.log('Error: ' + msg)
  console.log(err, err.stack)
  return -1
})

if (data === -1) {
  return 'Error while putting new object to S3'
}
  
console.log('Success: ' + msg);
console.log(data);
```

The code is still not nice and I'm grateful for suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Did you necessarily have to use Node.js? For gzipping, you can also use a Python Lambda function. With the `gzip`and `zipfile` libraries, it could be pretty easy:

```
gzipped_content = gzip.compress(f_in.read())
destinationbucket.upload_fileobj(io.BytesIO(gzipped_content),
                                                        final_file_path,
                                                        ExtraArgs={"ContentType": "text/plain"}
                                                )
```

There's a full tutorial for the lambda function here: https://medium.com/p/f7bccf0099c9